Loading custom unaccent rules into PostgreSQL Amazon RDS
I use PostgreSQL with unaccent extension in order to handle German umlauts.
By default, the mapping works in the following way:
Müller -> Muller, but this is not natural. Ü should be mapped into UE, Ö should be mapped into OE, but by default it is mapped to O.

Müller -> Muller // NOT GOOD
Müller -> Mueller // GOOD

In order to handle this, I edited the unaccent.rules file in /usr/local/share/postgresql/tsearch_data, as suggested by some german colleagues that stumbled upon this problem as well.
So, essentially, upon creating a PostgreSQL extension, in parallel, on the container initialization, I mount a custom rule file and replace it with the original one, and, voilà, I have a working solution! All I have to do is just to wrap the column name like this:
SELECT * FROM students
WHERE unaccent(name) ILIKE unaccent('Muel%')

This works on my local machine and all the environments where the DB lives inside a Docker container, but I'm not sure how I can make this work on Amazon RDS which is our production environment (since I don't have the access to the file system).

When I tried this a couple of years ago (around 2020) it was not possible on RDS. Amazon does not allow access on the file level. They would have to offer some workaround, which they didn't last time I checked. One of the downsides of cloud services.

You should write your own function that preprocesses the strings and makes your desired substitutions.

@LaurenzAlbe could you please provide an example how to do this? Also, if 'Müller' is stored in the DB, is there a way to match it both by 'Muller' and 'Mueller', or I have to choose one of them. Anyway, a code snippet or an example function would be extremely helpful. Thanks!

You won't be able to create a custom “unaccent” dictionary in a hosted database, since that requires file system access.
I recommend that you use a custom function like
CREATE FUNCTION normalized(text) RETURNS text
   IMMUTABLE PARALLEL SAFE
   RETURN unaccent(
             replace(
                replace(
                   replace(
                      replace(
                         lower($1), 'ö', 'oe'
                      ), 'ü', 'ue'
                   ), 'ä', 'ae'
                ), 'ß', 'ss'
             )
          );

Then you could create a text search index with
CREATE INDEX ON tab USING gin (to_tsvector('german', normalized(doc)));

You would apply the same normalization to documents and search strings:
SELECT ... FROM tab
WHERE to_tsvector('german', normalized(doc)) @@
      to_tsquery('german', normalized('Schöffen'));

